# How to align seaborn figure to right?

Tags: python, seaborn

[image]
I got these seaborn figures. As you can see, it is little bit messy because the length of y axis varialbes is different.
How can I align this figure to right?
This is my code.

```
for idx, feature in enumerate(['LANE_CODE', 'MOVEMENT_CODE','AREA_DAMAGED_CODE_MAIN']):
    plt.figure(figsize = (10,5))
    ax = sns.countplot(y = feature, hue = "cluster", data= analyzing_df)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You cannot align "the figure" to the right, because you have 3 different figures.

You may either

#### Create a single figure

```
fig,axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, figsize = (10,15))
for idx, feature in enumerate([...]):
    sns.countplot(y = feature, hue = "cluster", data= analyzing_df, ax=axes[idx])
plt.show()
```

#### Align the output images to the right

Use

```
%%HTML
<style>
img {float: right !important;}
</style>
```

to align the output from a cell to the right.